# Post to Facebook page feed without first liking the page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to post to a facebook page feed without first liking the page?

I tried the feed dialog using something like the code below --
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=X&to=Y&redirect_uri=Z
which resulted in an error "An invalid target was specified: Y. The target must be a page, event, or user that the actor can post on the wall of."

I also tried creating an access token from the page admin and then posting using the graph, but that resulted in the feed post coming from the admin and not the user who is posting.

I simply need the user to be able to post to the pages wall.  Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [FB docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/):

> feed
>
> This connection corresponds to the Page's Wall. You can create a link,
>   post or status message by issuing an HTTP POST request to the
>   PAGE_ID/feed connection. To see more details please see links, posts,
>   and status messages documentation.
>
> To impersonate the Page when posting to the wall (i.e. post as the
>   Page, and not the current user), you must use a Page access_token with
>   the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions, as described under
>   Page Access Tokens above.
>
> Posts may be targeted to countries, cities, regions or locales using
>   the targeting parameter. Please see Post for additional information.

**edit:**

Sorry, bad part above, correct is:

> posts 
>   Create
>
> You can create a post on a Page by issuing an HTTP POST request to
>   PAGE_ID/feed with the **publish_stream** and manage_pages permissions and
>   the following parameters.

Comment: as I mentioned above, you need to 'like' the page before you can post to the wall (as far as I can tell anyways).

Comment: Did you try permissions metioned above?

Comment: so do I need to get the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions from the current user or the page?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think **publish_stream** only

Comment: Yeah, that was all.  Thanks again!